# Splitting .txt file includes the .txt extension

Tags: python, split

So I have a lot of data files, which have a name similar to this:

> lvh_GTV_TwoField-3-401-86.txt

The thing that changes from file to file is the number `86` and `GTV`.

I'm trying to use this code to distinguish between files:

```
f.split('-')[3]
```

This, if I'm not mistaken, should split the file at the `-`, and then the 3rd, which is 86. In my case I would really like to use `int(f.split('-')[3])` because I need to reference it against another number, however, when splitting at the 3rd, the output is actually `86.txt` or so, and therefore I can't it as an integer.

So my question is: How do I split the file, so I only the the value 86, and not the `.txt` extension along with it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is very controlled, you could `splice` the string resulting, so something like:

```
f.split('-')[3][:-4]    # '86', take all chars except the last 4 (.txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the `os.path.splitext` function to remove the extension:

```
import os

os.path.splitext(f)[0].split('-')[3]
```

Or, more verbosely,

```
base, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
base.split('-')[3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [PyPI package `parse`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse):

```
from parse import parse

parse("lvh_{}_TwoField-3-401-{:d}.txt", "lvh_GTV_TwoField-3-401-86.txt")[1]
# => 86 (as an int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Python's build-in RegExp library](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html):

```
import re

m = re.match(
        "lvh_.+_TwoField-3-401-(?P<the_number>\d+)\.txt",
        "lvh_GTV_TwoField-3-401-86.txt"
)
the_number = int(m.group('the_number'))
```